# Silverstripe upgrade 3.6 > 4.0.2 install.php Parser Error unexpected T_String

Tags: composer-php, php-7.2, silverstripe-4

Im trying to get the ss upgrade to work (Upgrade with composer)

```
{
"name": "silverstripe/installer",
"description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
"require": {
"php": ">=7.2.3",
"silverstripe/cms": "4.0.2",
"silverstripe/framework": "4.0.2",
"silverstripe/reports": "^4.0",
"silverstripe/siteconfig": "^4.0",
"undefinedoffset/sortablegridfield": "dev-master",
"silverstripe/recipe-core": "^1.0",
"silverstripe/recipe-cms": "^1",
"symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions": "^3.1",
"unclecheese/betterbuttons": "dev-master",
"colymba/gridfield-bulk-editing-tools": "dev-master",
"jonom/focuspoint": "dev-master",
"silverstripe/blog": "^3.0",
"silverstripe/userforms": "^5.0",
"silverstripe/widgets": "^1.2",
"silverstripe/googlesitemaps": "^1.5",
"silverstripe/staticpublishqueue": "dev-master",
"silverstripe/asset-admin": "^1.0",
"cyber-duck/silverstripe-seo": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
"phpunit/PHPUnit": "^7.0"
},
"config": {
"process-timeout": 600
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
"project-files-installed": [
    ".htaccess",
    "index.php",
    "install-frameworkmissing.html",
    "install.php",
    "mysite/.htaccess",
    "mysite/_config.php",
    "mysite/_config/mysite.yml",
    "mysite/code/Page.php",
    "mysite/code/PageController.php",
    "web.config"
 ]
 }
 }
```

it looks like after the composer update, it isn't fully installed, not one page can be found, admin is not accessible. I changed the config files, removed deprecated parts, using the new .env files for database connections, as stated in the docs. But to no success yet...
I think it is because of a fatal error, that is shown when I access localhost/index.php, or when I try to reinstall from localhost/install.php.

The message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpParser\Error: Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on 
line 294 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\web\vendor\nikic\php-
parser\lib\PhpParser\ParserAbstract.php:293 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\web\vendor\nikic\php-
parser\lib\PhpParser\Parser\Multiple.php(50): PhpParser\ParserAbstract-
>parse('Skip to content...', Object(PhpParser\ErrorHandler\Throwing))
```

At first it was possible that it was caused by an older php version (php 5.3) I upgraded to php 7.2.3, but the parser problem stayed.

Anybody a clue what could cause this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you properly upgraded to PHP v7.2.3?

Comment: thats what php -v gives me?
Are there other ways to test this?

Comment: Place a file with the content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on your webserver and call it

Comment: could be some old (3rd party?) code that finally breaks with PHP7.2... What does `composer update --dry-run` put out? You can try without --dry-run and see if all modules are fine now. If something broke in a previous install, you can delete that module from /vendor/ to force a reinstall

Comment: Phpinfo also gives me 7.2.3.
Welll, I know its a third party package, but it's used internally by silverstripe, so one way or another, this should/could be fixed. I already deleted my vendor map, updated everything again. the problem stays. I wanted to post a bug on the github, but I am first trying to figure out if it is really a bug, or just some stupid configuration thing.

I hoped anybody would have had this. But All I found so far is, update your php! which i did....

Comment: Did you end up finding out the problem here?